# How do i change individual border colors in bootstrap 5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="m-3 p-3 border-5 border-top border-danger border-bottom border-primary">
  Border with different colors?
</div>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this maybe using [sass](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/borders/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in SCSS you should use BOM approch so you can write like this:

```
<div class="border border-top border-bottom">
```

Border with different colors?

Now scss:

.border {
&-bottom {
border-bottom-color: red
}
&-top {
border-top-color: green
}
}